# Handling soft keyboard events in appium-android

Tags: android, selenium, appium

How to handle soft keyboard and hide it using appium android.

Below is my scenario :

1. Open the flipkart app
2. Click on search icon
3. type some text [eg: cars]
4. Click search icon from the device keyboard

Below is the code I implemented:

```
driver.findElement(By.className(properties.getProperty("home_menu_className"))).click();
        System.out.println("clicked fist cross mark");
        driver.findElement(By.className(properties.getProperty("home_menu_className"))).click();
        System.out.println("click menu options");
        driver.findElementByName(properties.getProperty("home_menu_back_name")).click();
        System.out.println("clicked home back button");
        //WebElement search = driver.findElement(By.xpath(properties.getProperty("search_xpath")));
        //taction.tap(search);
        driver.rotate(ScreenOrientation.LANDSCAPE);
        driver.findElementByName(properties.getProperty("search_name")).click();
        System.out.println("clicked search icon");
        WebElement search_item = driver.findElementByName(properties.getProperty("search_edit_field_name"));
        search_item.sendKeys("cars");
        search_item.sendkeys(KEYS.ENTER);   
        System.out.println("entered search text");
        delay(8000);
```

> I used "driver.rotate(ScreenOrientation.LANDSCAPE);" in the code but
>   got error as  org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: An unknown
>   server-side error occurred while processing the command. (WARNING: The
>   server did not provide any stacktrace information)
>
> And am getting error on using driver.hideKeyboard();

Can anyone please let me know it ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is version of your Java client JARs.? and do you using webdriver/androiddriver/appiumdriver?

Comment: I am using 3.2.0 java client jars . Am using appium driver and android driver

Comment: Did you try ? `driver.navigate().back()` , it will help you to handle keyboard.

Comment: No. but driver.navigate().back(); will redirect to back page I think. Can you please tell me in detail I did not get the point here

Comment: Actually when keyboard is open and if you execute `driver.navigate().back()` , it will close keyboard , and if keyboard it not open and you execute `driver.navigate().back()` , then only it will redirect you to previous screen.

Comment: Thanks. I started learning appium few days back but getting struck with the methods. But my scenario is to click on search icon on the keyboard. How can I do that ?

Comment: I think for that you will have to do key press like enter  as we can not identify element id of search button of keyboard.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92685/discussion-between-helping-hands-and-naazneen3264).

Answer (score 1):

To hide keyboard, You can use :

```
//To hide keyboard. 
driver.hideKeyboard();
```

OR
to enter some key events use :

```
driver.press_keycode(KEY_CODE);    #KEY_CODE = 66 for ENTER
```

Refer below the URL to find KEY_CODES :
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code and it will works fine.

`driver.sendKeyEvent(AndroidKeyCode.ENTER);`

Answer (score 0):

Add these capabilities in your test to hide the keyboard:

```
capabilities.setCapability("unicodeKeyboard", true);
capabilities.setCapability("resetKeyboard", true);
```